# Database design for three completely different profiles

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, normalization

I have question regarding `database design` for three completely different profiles which have only common columns are `user_id` and `password`.

Let's say I have profile tables and its columns like,

**Profile1** : user_id, password, profile1_col1, profile1_col2, ...

**Profile2** : user_id, password, profile2_col1, profile2_col2, ...

**Profile3** : user_id, password, profile3_col1, profile3_col2, ...

So, how can I `normalize` these tables so that I can make a common login module for these profiles?

Note : I didn't give proper column names because right now I don't have any similar requirement.

Comment: You don't provide enough information about the profiles to properly answer the question.  Split the information into a User table and one or more Profile tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You may use inheritance. 
Defining a new entity as the base table for (profile-type-one, profile-type-two,...) to satisfy login-able.
 May naming it abstract-profile will be rational.
 Having a zero-or-one relation will cause primary key of this abstract-profile table being the primary key of (profile-type-one, profile-type-two,...).
 Other tables like login-history, user-action-trace ... will have a relation to this base table.